# Does DJI's Mobile Android SDK support Samsung S7, S8, or Google Pixel?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I want to know if DJI's Mobile SDK supports the following devices:

- Samsung S7
- Sumsung S8
- Google Pixel

The [docs](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-prerequisits.html) say that the Mobile SDK supports these devices:

> Samsung tabs 705c, Samsung S6, Samsung S5, Samsung NOTE4, Samsung NOTE3, Google Nexus 9, Google Nexus 7 II, Ascend Mate7, Huawei Mate 8, Nubia Z7 mini, SONY Xperia Z3, MI 3, MI PAD

But most of those are discontinued or not available in the U.S. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone wants to know what makes these phones special - they all have ARM processors, the DJI Android SDK unfortunately only works on these types of processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we do support these devices. We will get the docs updated.

Comment: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-prerequisits.html